# Ruby on Rails - rake routes giving error about a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have this model:

```
class Kpi
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  #include Mongoid::Document

  field :number_of_users,      :type => Integer, :default => 0
end
```

and when I ran rake routes, I got this error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `field' for Kpi:Class
```

any idea why that would happen?

Thanks!

Comment: uncomment `#include Mongoid::Document`

Comment: @stefan thanks, but I only commented it because with it, it also wasn't working :)

Comment: And you should `include Mongoid::Document` first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rake routes` loads your environment -> loads your code. So if there's an error in your code, it won't show your routes. In your case, you should uncomment `include Mongoid::Document`

EDIT

So it's not working even with it ? Hm, maybe include `Document` before `Timestamps` ? Kind of a long shot here

Comment: trying your second suggestion...will let you know how it goes :)

Comment: It actually worked.  Now I am onto the next error which is this: undefined local variable or method `user' for Program:Class ...so that was the right solution :)

Comment: Actually it makes sense. `Timestamps` must have a hook when included which depends on what is def' in `Document`.